# Get OS version via Flash

Tags: flash

I was wondering if the OS version (Windows XP Home, Windows XP Pro, Windows Vista Ultimate, Windows Vista Business, etc...) is available via some kind of a variable in Flash.

Thanks,

Roy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, to some extent. Check out the os property on the Capabilities object [here](http://injun.ru/flash10api/flash/system/Capabilities.html#os):

> os:String  [read-only]
>
> Language Version :     ActionScript 3.0
>
> Player Version :   Flash Player 9
>
> **Specifies the current operating system.** The os property can return the following strings: "Windows XP", "Windows 2000", "Windows NT", "Windows 98/ME", "Windows 95", "Windows CE" (available only in Flash Player SDK, not in the desktop version), "Linux", and "MacOS". The server string is OS.

Comment: I need the exact version of OS, Windows XP or windows Vista isn't enough. There are sub versions/editions. Any other ideas?

Comment: Afraid not -- that's all the info the Flash API provides.

Answer (score 0):

> I need the exact version of OS, Windows XP or windows Vista isn't enough. There are sub versions/editions.

It's a bit hacky, but you can get the exact OS version from the user-agent string.

The string can be obtained using

```
ExternalInterface.call("window.navigator.userAgent.toString")
```